# Creating atom plugin, importing from github

Tags: javascript, git, atom-editor

I m actually building an atom plugin at my work and I pushed it to a repository.

Unfortunately, when I clone this repository inside of my ~/github (with other custom plugin that I've  built on this second computer), nothing happens and my plugin isn't present in my atom plugin list.

Is there any way to import this external plugin directly inside of my ide so I can work on it from both of my computers ?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the cloned directory in terminal then

```
apm install
apm link .
```